# Embed Python 3.5 with tkinter support on Windows

Tags: c, windows, tkinter, python-3.5, python-embedding

My project structure looks like this:

```
emb
|   CMakeLists.txt
|   main.c
|   python35.lib
|   stdlib.zip
|   _tkinter.pyd
|
+---include
|   |
|   |   abstract.h
|   |   accu.h
|   |   asdl.h
...
|   |   warnings.h
|   |   weakrefobject.h
|
+---build
|   |   emb.exe
```

**stdlib.zip** contains the *DLLs*, *Lib* and *site-packages* directories from Python 3.5.2 installation whose paths are appended to `sys.path`. I'm implicitly loading **python35.dll** by linking to **python35.lib** which contains the stubs for all of the exported functions in the DLL. Here's the contents of **CMakeLists.txt**:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(embpython)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.c)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES})

set(PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR include)
include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR})

target_link_libraries(
        ${PROJECT_NAME}
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/python35.lib
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/_tkinter.pyd)
```

And here's the contents of **main.c**:

```
#include <Python.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    wchar_t* program_name;
    wchar_t* sys_path;
    char* path;

    program_name = Py_DecodeLocale(argv[0], NULL);
    if (program_name == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: cannot decode argv[0]\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    Py_SetProgramName(program_name);

    path = "stdlib.zip;stdlib.zip/DLLs;stdlib.zip/Lib;"
        "stdlib.zip/site-packages";
    sys_path = Py_DecodeLocale(path, NULL);
    Py_SetPath(sys_path);

    Py_Initialize();

    PySys_SetArgv(argc, argv);

    PyRun_SimpleString("import tkinter\n");

    Py_Finalize();
    PyMem_RawFree(sys_path);
    PyMem_RawFree(program_name);
    return 0;
}
```

Now, here's the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File " ... emb\stdlib.zip\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Disclaimer

This answer does not purport to be the correct or best way to embed Python 3.5 with Tkinter support. The step-by-step format only reflects the fact that this was how I managed to get everything working on my machine, and since I am unable to test this solution elsewhere, I cannot confirm that it will work in all or even most cases.

---

### How I did it

1. Create *include*, *lib*, *lib\python35* and *src* directories in the
   project root directory.
2. Copy all files inside of *path\to\python35\include* to the *include* directory in the project root directory.
3. Zip all files inside of *path\to\python35\Lib* into a single file called **stdlib.zip** and put it in the project root directory.¹
4. Copy all files inside of *path\to\python35\DLLs* to the *lib\python35* directory in the project root directory. The **_tkinter.pyd** library file should be inside.²
5. Copy the **libpython35.a** import library from *path\to\python35\libs* to the **lib** directory in the project root directory.
6. Create a **main.py** file inside of the *src* directory in the project root directory with the following contents:

   ```
   import tkinter as tk

   def run():
       root = tk.Tk()
       root.mainloop()
   ```
7. Zip **main.py** into a single file called **source.zip** and put it in the project root directory.
8. Create a **main.c** file inside of the *src* directory in the project root directory with the following contents:

   ```
   // WARNING: I did not check for errors but you definitely should!

   #import <Python.h>

   static const char* SYS_PATH = "source.zip;stdlib.zip;lib/python35";

   int main(int argc, char** argv)
   {
       wchar_t* program = NULL;
       wchar_t** wargv = NULL;
       wchar_t* sys_path = NULL;
       int i;

       program = Py_DecodeLocale(argv[0], NULL);
       Py_SetProgramName(program);

       sys_path = Py_DecodeLocale(SYS_PATH, NULL);
       Py_SetPath(sys_path);

       Py_Initialize();

       wargv = (wchar_t**) malloc(argc * sizeof(wchar_t*));
       for (i = 0; i < argc; i++)
           wargv[i] = Py_DecodeLocale(argv[i], NULL);
       PySys_SetArgv(argc, wargv);

       PyRun_SimpleString("import main\n"
                          "main.run()\n");

       Py_Finalize();
       PyMem_RawFree(program);
       PyMem_RawFree(sys_path);
       for (i = 0; i < argc; i++)
           PyMem_RawFree(wargv[i]);
       free(wargv);
       return 0;
   }
   ```
9. Create a **CMakeLists.txt** file in the project root directory with the following contents:

   ```
   cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
   project(emb)

   set(SOURCE_FILES src/main.c)
   add_executable(emb ${SOURCE_FILES})

   include_directories(include)

   add_library(libpython35 STATIC IMPORTED)
   set_property(
       TARGET libpython35 PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION
       ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/lib/libpython35.a)

   target_link_libraries(emb libpython35)
   ```
10. Build and run. If you did everything correctly up to this point, you should see something like this:

    ```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
      File "C:\path\to\project\stdlib.zip\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1868, in __init__
    _tkinter.TclError: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories:
        C:/path/to/project/lib/lib/tcl8.6
        C:/path/to/project/lib/tcl8.6 
        C:/path/to/project/library
        C:/path/to/project/tcl8.6.4/library
    ```

    Tcl and Tk directories are nowhere to be found. We need to bring those in and update the TCL_LIBRARY enviroment variable.
11. Copy *tcl8.6* and **tk8.6** directories from *C:\path\to\python35\tcl* to the *lib* directory in the project root directory.
12. Create and set the TCL_LIBRARY environment variable to `"lib\tcl8.6"`.

Everything should work now.

¹ <sub>This is not strictly necessary. You could just as well keep your .py files in a directory and append its path to `sys.path`.</sub>

² <sub>The reason why python was raising an `ImportError` before was because *_tkinter.pyd* was inside a zip file and thus could not be loaded.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Just updating after Jovito answered everything to specify how to make it a light installation (steps 3 to 5 this saves space):

Copy the `_tkinter.pyd` file mine is in `\Pythonpath\DLLs\` into the directory you have the `python35.dll` located for your embedded installation. You also need 2 DLLs for `tkinter` to work in the same location `tcl86t.dll` and `tk86t.dll`

You need these directories: `\Pythonpath\Lib\tkinter`and `\Pythonpath\tcl\tcl8.6` and `\Pythonpath\tcl\tk8.6` and have to set in your `main.py` script as shown below:

```
import os
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = "tcl//tcl8.6"
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = "tcl//tk8.6"
```

That makes Jovito's answer as lightweight as possible.  Use the rest of his answer.  Works for me.

Comment: Please, see my answer.

Comment: @Jovito I see in step 8 there appears to be an error when setting the `wargv malloc` for use in `PySys_SetArgv(argc, wargc)` - "a value of type "void *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "wchar_t **" - thanks for your answer BTW this is the last step I have to get it working since Tkinter requires ARGV to be set in the C++.

Comment: The call should be `PySys_SetArgv(argc, wargv)`.

Comment: @Jovito that was a typo I couldn't edit after 5m.  The compiler error is "a value of type "void" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "wchar_t **" right at `wargv = malloc(argc * sizeof(wchar_t*));`